# Composer psr-4 autoload cannot found file

Tags: php, composer-php

I am still learning to use php composer

i have a directory structure like this :

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOtpl.png)

and this is my  composer.json

```
  {
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Kct\\": "lib/"
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my index.php file i am trying to load Class tes in tesdir.php

```
<?php 
// file: index.php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$x = new \Kct\Tesdir\Tes();
var_dump($x->tes());   //output: 'GET'
```

my tesdir.php :

```
<?php 
namespace Kct\Tesdir;

    class Tes {

        public function tes() {
            return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        }

    }
```

now if I open index.php in my localhost I got and error like this :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Kct\Tesdir\Tes' not found in /var/www/html/tesComposer/index.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/tesComposer/index.php on line 6
```

can someone explain why.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tesdir.php should be named Tes.php. The name of the file should match the name of the class.

See the [PSR-4 examples](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)